# Increasing column count in GridLayoutManager causing significant jank

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

My app allows user to increase column count to 5. When column is set to 1-4 there seems to be no jank.

It is a Android gallery app using recyclerview and Glide.

[image]

When column is set to 5 is when the jank starts to occur

[image]

You can see the groups of red. That is when the recyclerview is scrolled quickly. But scrolling quickly on the systrace above (column 1-4) did not cause jank.

I understand that there are many more imageview's on screen when column count is set to 5 and that when scrolling fast its trying to load so many at once.

I have tried stripping everything out of my layout and adapter to bare minimum to get to this point but still getting jank when i increase to 5 columns.

**My question is there anything I can do to make this better?**

GlideModule

```
 @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        MemorySizeCalculator calculator = new MemorySizeCalculator.Builder(context)
            .setMemoryCacheScreens(5)
            .build();
        builder.setMemoryCache(new LruResourceCache(calculator.getMemoryCacheSize()));
        MemorySizeCalculator calculator2 = new MemorySizeCalculator.Builder(context)
            .setBitmapPoolScreens(5)
            .build();
        builder.setBitmapPool(new LruBitmapPool(calculator2.getBitmapPoolSize()));
        int diskCacheSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 200; // 200 MB
        builder.setDiskCache(new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, diskCacheSizeBytes));

        builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(
            new RequestOptions()
                //.placeholder(getPlaceHolder())
                //.error(getErrorPlaceHolder())
                //todo added for emulator
                //.disallowHardwareConfig()
                .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL));

    }
```

Fragment

```
 int spanCount = columnsCount();
 GridSpacingItemDecoration spacingDecoration = new GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, Measure.pxToDp(3, act), true);
 rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
 rv.addItemDecoration(spacingDecoration);

 mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), spanCount);
 mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
 @Override
 public int getSpanSize(int position) {
       if (mAdapter.getAllItems().get(position).getType() == TypeItem.TYPE_HEAD){
             return spanCount;
             } else {
               return 1;
             }
            }
        });

rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new MediaAdapter3(getContext(), GlideApp.with(this), sortingMode(), sortingOrder());
rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Bindview of Adapter

```
Key signature = new MediaStoreSignature(media.getMimeType(), media.getDateModified(), media.getOrientation());
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .signature(signature)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(placeholder);

            glide
                .load(media.getUri())
                .apply(options)
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                .into(imageView);
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<***.SquareRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/media_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/thumb_height">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/photo_preview"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</***.SquareRelativeLayout>
```